# How to find out if iTerm is installed on a mac from within a shell script?

Tags: macos, command-line, install, iterm

I am writing an automated script that will install iTerm2 if it's not already installed. What's a good way of checking if iTerm2 is already installed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The open command will open it no matter where the person has it installed (you don’t have to put an app in /Applications on macOS).

```
open -a iTerm.app
```

You could search using spotlight as well

```
 mdfind "kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier == com.googlecode.iterm2"
```

Comment: Nice use of Spotlight!

Comment: Using `open -a iTerm.app` in an automated shell script to test something is very inconvenient...

Comment: @klanomath it’s bad form in an installer as well, since you shouldn’t assume anyone has logged in yet. I should update this for packaging guidelines.... the only way would be to tell someone, “we’re about to open iTerm 2, click here to download it if the app doesn’t open shortly...”

Comment: You can use `if ! [ $(mdfind "kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier == com.googlecode.iterm2") ]; then [install iTerm2] else [already installed]` in a script...

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Great usage of Spotlight

Comment: Is `iterm` installed on Mac by default and iterm2 not? So I can get iterm2 and have  e.g. windowsplitting which iterm does not have?

Comment: Neither are default - only terminal.app is standard on macOS. @Timo once you find your iTerm application, you could use `mdls` to show all the metadata and see what the internal and friendly names are.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's installed in the standard Applications folder, use

```
if [[ ! -d /Applications/iTerm.app ]]; then
    # proceed with installing iTerm
fi
```

If you want to cover for situations where iTerm isn't installed in the standard location, you might use

```
open -g -j -a iTerm 2>/dev/null
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    sleep 3
    osascript -e 'tell application "iTerm" to quit'
else
    # install iTerm
fi
```

If iTerm is already running it will exit in this case.

Comment: Feel free to suck in my `mdfind` into your much more complete answer if you would like to...

Comment: @bmike Actually I just wanted to delete mine after seeing your `mdfind` magic :-)

Comment: Metadata is becoming my super power  - `mdls` and `xattr` all the things!

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two places where iTerm.app might be found, either in the `/Applications/` folder (99% of the time) or the user’s own `$HOME/Applications/` folder (very rare, but possible).

You can check to see if it is in either of those places like so:

```
if [ ! -d '/Applications/iTerm.app' -a ! -d "$HOME/Applications/iTerm.app" ]
then

    echo 'iTerm is not installed'

fi
```

I’ll also mention that I already have a script that will download and install the latest version of iTerm:

https://github.com/tjluoma/di/blob/master/di-iterm.sh

which is part of my [di - download &  install](https://github.com/tjluoma/di/) repo, which will do this for 300+ Mac apps.

`di-iterm.sh` uses the official Sparkle / XML feed to check for the latest version, and there are ways to use the beta or nightly builds if you prefer one of those options.

If it is already installed and up-to-date, it will just report that information and exit.

If it is *not* installed or out-of-date, the script will download the latest version, install it, and move the old version to the trash.

If you have questions or problems, feel free to leave me an issue on GitHub or email me (my email is in the script). Please also feel free to use / adapt my script as a starting point if you want to do something different.

Comment: Super bonus tool - di-licious